# Sonar Java plugin - link scanned files with sonar component

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm writing a plugin for scanning java files for SonarQube 6.2. The scanning is done by class implementing `JavaFileScanner` interface of Java plugin. My scanner logs some issues (if found something) and when it finishes it needs to log the metric measurements on scanned class. Is it possible to obtain SonarComponent in `JavaFileScanner` (like `org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.SensorContext.module()`)?

Comment: What is your plugin trying to achieve? If you "just" want to create rules of your own, then you should take a look at https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/tree/master/java-custom-rules

Comment: My plugin stores data about files parsed in external DB (for computing thresholds). It needs to identify the file component and process it within a measure computer to calculate metrics using those thresholds from DB.